# McCulloch-Pitts neuron NAND

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, computer-science

A MP neuron of NAND can be constructed using the truth table below:

```
P Q   P(and not)Q
1 1        0
1 0        1
0 1        0
0 0        0
```

The neuron that shows this:

```
Inputs:  
    P +2
    Q -1
If the threshold is 2
```

This will give an output of `Y=1`

My professor seemed confused and didn't clarify why this isn't correct when it is (to the best of my knowledge). Did he make a mistake or have i got this wrong?

A solution would be great.

Side note: I have sketched out this neuron but cannot draw on this page (new to SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all NAND is not "and not" but "not and", the logical table is

```
P Q   NAND(P,Q) 
1 1        0
1 0        1
0 1        1
0 0        1
```

second of all, there is nothing hard about NAND nor your gate. The "only" problematic one is XOR (and nXOR).

```
P Q    XOR(P,Q) 
1 1        0
1 0        1
0 1        1
0 0        0
```

So:

- single perceptron can easily represent both NAND(p,q) = NOT(AND(p,q)) as well as AND(p, NOT(q)) (which you call NAND).
- the impossible to represent gate is XOR and its negation.